# Mahapps metro badged control how to update value of badge

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am using the mahapps metro app to make a gui in wpf. I have used the code

```
<Controls:Badged Badge="{Binding Path=BadgeValue}">
  <!-- Control to wrap goes here -->
  <Button Content="Notifications" />
</Controls:Badged>
```

Say, if i want to update the 'BadgeValue' in the notifications callback, how do i go about doing this? plz help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `BadgeValue` source property that you bind to in your XAML and raise the `PropertyChanged` event, just like you would update any other data-bound property.

Here is an example for you:

**View Model:**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _badgeValue;
    public string BadgeValue
    {
        get { return _badgeValue; }
        set { _badgeValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.BadgeValue = "new value...";
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Controls:Badged Badge="{Binding Path=BadgeValue}">
    <Button Content="Notifications" />
</Controls:Badged>
<Button Content="Update" Click="Button_Click" />
```